# If I know the parameters of a probability distribution, do I also know the underlying probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory

If I have a probability model $(\Omega, \mathcal{F, P})$ with an associated probability distribution, e.g. $Normal(\mu, \sigma)$, and, the parameters $\mu, \sigma$ are known, is the probability measure also known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not.

The probability distribution $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma)$ is a measure

$$\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1]$$

This depends in no way on the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ of the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}).$

Comment: I don't see the difference. If I have a probability space including a probability measure on the $\sigma$-algebra in that probability space, and I know the probability distribution (parameters are known) then that probability distribution reflects the probabilities given by the probability measure, right?

Comment: Nope! Not at all! As I said, a probability distribution is just a probability measure on the Borel sets $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ of the real numbers. This has nothing to do with the probability space you mention! Now, let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on your probability space. Then it is true that the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ of your probability space induces a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X: \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1]$ via $\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$. But you are asking about the converse.When you talk about a "Normal distribution" [continued]

Comment: then you just talk about a probability measure on the Borel sets. For example, if I tell you: that random variable follows a normal distribution with certain parameters, there is no way for you to tell me on which probability space this random variables lives.